# Gradle sync failed error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.How to fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl2eg.png)

Comment: are you trying to import a new project with a module?

Comment: Question is not qualified for up vote but make sure buildToolsVersion is installed and root>Gradle version is same as Android Studio version. Checkout dependencies

Comment: try to check the package name in gradle file and then sync it.
and clean the project

Answer (score 0):

Please try this under **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart** you'll find an option that lets you either invalidate the caches (and you'll have to rebuild indexes again), or just restart the IDE.